# A jQuery search box, search results does not match input

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, delay

Firstly, the title was the best I could come up with.

I have written a very short little script to perform live search.

The basics of it is:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.SearchThing = function (options) {
        options = $.extend({
            MaxCount: 5,
            inputField: '#search_input',
            sugestBox: '#search_sugest'
        }, options);

        var input = $(options.inputField);
        var sugest = $(options.sugestBox);
        sugest.hide();

        input.keyup(function (e) {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                //Other keys.
                default:
                    queryServer(this.value);
            }
        });

        function queryServer(value) {
            var url = "/search/get?query=" + value; // value;
            $.getJSON(url, function (result) {
                if (result.Results < 1) {
                    sugest.hide();
                    return;
                }

                sugest.children().each(function (idx, itm) {
                    $(itm).remove();
                });
                sugest.show();

                //Build box.
            }
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And that almost works just fine. There is 2 things to be desired though. One that is not really that important and then another which is actually a bug, that might be solved by the other though, I don't know. But here they are:

### BUG: Results does not always match whats in the "input field"

What this means is that if I type "ASD" it performs a search for "ASD", so if i say type "ASD" followed by a rapid "backspace" it should search for "AS", however now and then it seems to end up with the results for "ASD".

I know this because I currently haven't implemented the search back-end, so I return a static list where the first element is the search term.

I figure that this may be because the search for "AS" returned sooner than the search for "ASD" so the results are applied in the order -> "A", "AS", "AS", "ASD" where they should be applied in the order "A", "AS", "ASD", "AS"....

It also occurs that if I type "ASD" it will apply it in order -> "A", "ASD", "AS". (Same thing happens, the search for "ASD" returns before the search for "AS")

***Note:** Short search terms like "ASD" rarely trigger this bug, longer ones with more rapid typing is more likey to do so, I used the short one here to make the description of the problem easier.*

Can anyone suggest a good solution to that?

### DESIRED: A Small delay before a search is submitted, if keystrokes are rapid only the last "value" is processed.

This may actually solve the issue above, actually highly likely to do so I think.

I have looked shortly at "delay", but since it can't "cancel" the execution (as far as I understood it) it would require allot of implementation as I see it, but maybe someone has a brilliant idea on that part.

Otherwise does anyone has any other ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for all of this is that request-response takes longer than the next key press, so the previous results show up.

I think you should be able to fix both "issues" with a single trick:

```
var delayTime = 500;
var lastTimeout = null;
var input = $(options.inputField);
var sugest = $(options.sugestBox);
sugest.hide();

input.keyup(function (e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        //Other keys.
        default:
            if (lastTimeout != null) {
                clearTimeout(lastTimeout);
            }
            lastTimeout = setTimeout('queryServer("'+this.value+'")', delayTime);
    }
});

function queryServer(value) {
    lastTimeout = null;
    // ... all the rest as before ...
};
```

This will show the suggestions only 0.5 second after you stop typing (or make a pause this long).

Comment: Cheers, however it doesn't seem to work... But that is properly my own fault, I left something out of the code that I did not think was essential, however since this doesn't work it might be???... I have edited the original sample. I am guessing the "string" given in the set timeout is just mussing something. Since it is an "internal" function... or what we might call it in JS??... Or will I have to rewrite it to be "public"... (would be according to the jQuery plugin guide lines)

Comment: now that's a scope problem (which was not apparent in the initial formulation of the question) - timeout will be called on a global scope, so you will need an object reference somewhere (exposing only the function to global scope will not be enough, because you use local 'suggest' variable inside the function)

Comment: Never mind. I found out how to make it work. Ill make a answer with the details as code it comments are real messy. So thanks.

Comment: No I know that, that is why I said that it was properly my own fault... Meaning your answer was good in the context you had. Rewriting it to be public the "jQuery way" would work, it keeps the function internal in a collection of functions, it is then called using e.g. $('.search').SearchThing('queryServer', this.value);... so that should work, however since I could pass a function in the "setTimeout" rather than a string, that seem to be a better way.

Comment: Hmmm.... Actually I can still provoke it, question is if there is much to do about it.

If I in my search handler delay the response with e.g. 1 second in the case that it contains "1000", i can then have the term "asd1000asd" if I delete "a" then "0" so it becomes "asd100sd" where i delay my typing between the two deletes (so that it fires of a search for "asd1000sd" then "asd100sd", because "asd1000sd" takes one second longer than the search for "asd100sd", that becomes the end result... obviously this is a simulation of variation in how long a search takes.

Comment: I have removed the "Answered" mark for for now, and I will then leave it open for a couple of days, to see if I can get some additional ideas from others. Then I will mark it "Answered" again.

Comment: Found a solution to that as well, can't figure if it has any other implications though, so marked your answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on mkilmanas's awnser, this is what worked:

```
if (lastTimeout != null) {
    window.clearTimeout(lastTimeout);
}

var value = this.value;
lastTimeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
    queryServer(value);
}, 300); //Choose a bit shorter timeout since 500 actually gave a "clunky" feeling.
```

except for a detail, if searches are submitted in a order say "A" then "AB" (because we are typing slow), if "A" takes 1000ms to perform, but "AB" only takes 100ms then "A" returns later than "AB" and the same issue arises.

I might have solved this by returning the original Query from the server, and then add the following check:

```
        var url = "/search/get?query=" + value; // value;
        $.getJSON(url, function (result) {
            if (result.Results < 1) {
                sugest.hide();
                return;
            }
            if (input.val() != result.Query) {
                return;
            }
```

This should filter out results that are delayed compared to later queries that returned there results faster, I can't think up any other implications of doing that.

Comment: Could you share the complete script that works? Could be useful to me (and others). Thanks!

Comment: I Have posted a full solution similar to the end script, the difference is that I have 3 areas I return instead of one.

But the rest is the same.

But I am not sure how usefull it really is in the light of it being heavily tailored to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Full Source for Eduardo Molteni, Note that this is tailored a great deal to how my site is build and how the server responds to the query, so it will most likely only server as a inspiration.

Also note that it puts requirements on the HTML behind.

The idea behind "MyArea" in the code bellow is because I have cut out the areas I perform search within and replaced it with a single "MyArea", this is to show that it supports showing a grouped set of results.

the appendSection should be called for each area you wish, and this is where you would structure the HTML you would like to come out of it, note that I as an example has a "Header" etc. You may not wan't that.

```
// Copyright 2012 Jens Melgaard, www.dotjem.com
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
(function ($) {
    $.fn.dotJEMSearch = function (options) {
        options = $.extend({
            inputField: '#search_input',
            sugestBox: '#search_sugest'
        }, options);

        var timeout = null;
        var input = $(options.inputField);
        var sugest = $(options.sugestBox);
        var current = -1;
        var displayed = 0;
        var items = [];

        sugest.hide();

        input.blur(function () { sugest.hide(); });
        input.focus(function () { if (displayed > 0) { sugest.show(); } });
        input.keydown(function (e) { if (e.keyCode == 13) e.preventDefault(); });
        input.keyup(function (e) {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 13: //Return Key
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (current != -1) {
                        window.location.href = items[current].Url;
                    } else {
                        window.location.href = '/search?query=' + this.value;
                    }
                    return false;

                case 38: //up key
                    selectItem(current - 1);
                    return false;

                case 40: //up key
                    selectItem(current + 1);
                    return false;

                default:
                    if (timeout != null) {
                        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
                    }

                    var value = this.value;
                    timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
                        queryServer(value);
                    }, 200);
            }
        });

        function queryServer(value) {
            timeout = null;

            var url = "/search/get?query=" + value;
            $.getJSON(url, function (result) {
                items = [];
                displayed = 0;
                if (result.Results < 1) {
                    sugest.hide();
                    return;
                }
                if (input.val() != result.Query) {
                    return;
                }

                sugest.children().each(function (idx, itm) {
                    $(itm).remove();
                });
                sugest.show();
                appendSection('Search Results', result.MyArea);
            });
        };

        function appendSection(heading, elements) {
                    if (elements.Count > 0) {
            var show = elements.Items.length;
            sugest.append('<h1>' + heading + '<em>' + show + ' of ' + elements.Count + '</em></h1>');

            var elm = $('<ul>');
            for (var i = 0; i < show; i++) {
                var item = elements.Items[i];
                var listElm = $('<li><a href="' + item.Href + '">' + item.Title + '</a></li>');

                (function (index) {
                    listElm.hover(function () { selectItem(index); }, function () { deselect(); });
                })(displayed);
                items[displayed++] = { Elm: listElm, Url: item.Href };
                elm.append(listElm);
            }
            sugest.append(elm);
        };

        function selectItem(idx) {
            deselect();
            current = (idx + items.length) % items.length;
            $(items[current].Elm).addClass('active');
        };

        function deselect() {
            if (current < 0)
                return;
            $(items[current].Elm).removeClass('active');
            current = -1;
        };

    };
})(jQuery);
```

The HTML Piece

```
                <form id="search" class="search" name="search_form">
                    <input type="text" name="query" autocomplete="off" id="search_input"/>
                    <div id="search_sugest" style="display: none;">
                    </div>
                </form>

    <!-- somewhere at the bottom-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('.search').dotJEMSearch();
        });
    </script>
```

The next part is how the "JSON" format is structured. In my case this is returned by a HTTP Handler server side (ASP.NET).

```
@"{  ""Results"": 33,
     ""Query"": """ + query + @""",
     ""MyArea"": {
         ""Count"": 21,
         ""Items"": [
       { ""Title"": ""One"", ""Desc"": ""description"", ""Href"": ""/link"" },
       { ""Title"": ""Two"", ""Desc"": ""description"", ""Href"": ""/link"" },
       { ""Title"": ""Three"", ""Desc"": ""description"", ""Href"": ""/link"" },
       { ""Title"": ""Four"", ""Desc"": ""description"", ""Href"": ""/link"" },
       { ""Title"": ""Five"", ""Desc"": ""description"", ""Href"": ""/link"" }
                    ]
               }
  }";
```

Comment: Thanks! I was interested in how do you manage other aspects of the search like selecting the result or hiding the suggest div. I ended up doing something different, because I need the user to scroll the suggest result. Thanks again! it's very useful to learn from others code